# Class is not defined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For context, I am working on a game using Phaser framework. However, this question is generally geared at Javascript.

I have defined the following class in my main.js file via a function constructor:

```
function AchievementsMenu() {

    this.lastY = 43 * c.length 
}
```

However, when making a prototype `AchievementsMenu.prototype = Object.create( Phaser.Group.prototype );` I get the error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: AchievementsMenu is not defined'.

I understand that I have simply created a function class defining the object without actually making an instance of it. I shouldn't need to, though, to create a prototype method, right?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

```
import 'pixi'
import 'p2'
import Phaser from 'phaser'

import * as AM from './managers/AchievementManager.js'
import * as HG from './managers/hgManager.js'
import * as DM from './managers/dataManager.js'

//Configs for initializing Phaser framework
var cfg = {
        width: 1334,
        height: 750,
        renderer: Phaser.WEBGL,
        parent: "gameDiv",
        enableDebug: !1,
        transparent: !1,
        antialias: !1
    },

    game = new Phaser.Game(cfg);

game.achievementManager = new AM.AchievementManager( game );
game.hgManager = new HG.HGManager();
game.dataManager = new DM.DataManager( game );

//A decent chunk of the class
function AchievementsMenu() {
    Phaser.Group.call(this, game);

    var a = game.add.image(0, 0, "MainUI", "Achievements/Achievements_TextBG_Disabled.png");
    a.anchor.setTo(.5),
    a.scale.setTo(200),
    a.alpha = .4,
    a.tint = 0,
    a.inputEnabled = !0,
    a.events.onInputUp.add(this.onPressBG, this),
    this.add(a);


    var b = game.add.image(0, 0, "MainUI", "Achievements/Achievements_BG.png");
    b.inputEnabled = !0,
    b.events.onInputDown.add(this.onStartDrag, this),
    b.events.onInputUp.add(this.onEndDrag, this),
    this.add(b),

    this.add(this.game.add.bitmapText(15, 2, "Omnes", "Achievements", 28)),
    this.scrollableContent = game.add.group(),
    this.add(this.scrollableContent);

    for (var c = this.game.constants.achievements, d = this.game.playerData.achievements, e = 0; e < c.length; e++) {
        var f = 80 * e + 35;

        if (d.indexOf(e) == -1){
            this.game.add.image(10, f, "MainUI", "Achievements/Achievements_TextBG_Disabled.png", this.scrollableContent),
            this.game.add.image(15, f + 4, "MainUI", "Achievements/Achievements_Icon_Locked.png", this.scrollableContent);
        }

        else {
            this.game.add.image(10, f, "MainUI", "Achievements/Achievements_TextBG_Enabled.png", this.scrollableContent),
            this.game.add.image(15, f + 4, "MainUI", "Achievements/Achievements_Icon_0" + e + ".png", this.scrollableContent);
            var g = this.game.add.bitmapText(450, f + 25, "Omnes", "Completed", 20, this.scrollableContent);
            g.tint = 7454787
        }

        this.game.add.bitmapText(75, f + 10, "Omnes", c[e].name, 25, this.scrollableContent),
        this.game.add.bitmapText(75, f + 35, "Omnes", c[e].description, 20, this.scrollableContent)
    }

    this.lastY = 43 * c.length; 
}

AchievementsMenu.prototype = Object.create( Phaser.Group.prototype );

AchievementsMenu.prototype.onPressBG = function() {
    this.visible = !1
};
```

Comment: You don't need to create an instance to extend the prototype. When the object is instanced, the prototypes will inherit if set up correctly.

Comment: I don't get that error. Are these 2 code blocks in the same file?

Comment: @SunnyPatel Yes, they are in the main.js file

Comment: I made a simple example, and don't have any issues: [TIO](https://tio.run/##XYyxCsIwEIb3PMWNjdAsdSsOPoA4Oybn2aTEu9JcCyI@e@wiQr/th@//Rr/6gnOatA0@UG5Z7lTrY2HUJAxnjIlWehJruRAvjYW3MbChMRWXfdEbnODYwQHQZeJBI5iP2f/cNIuKviba7GsYCdXhTF6p@c2/YXtjULhIJpdlaPYx29f6BQ). Can you recreate the problem?

Comment: Where does the variable `c` come from? Is this function definition inside another function? Then the name `AchievementsMenu` is local to that scope.

Comment: @SunnyPatel Okay so a normal `console.log( AchievementsMenu );` gives me the same error. Similarly, if I pop exactly what you put, `AchievementsMenu.prototype = Object.create( Object.prototype );` I also get the same error. "Normal" prototype extensions like `AchievementsMenu.prototype.onPressBG = function() {
    this.visible = !1
}` also give me the same error.

Comment: @Barmar the `c` is defined locally, and `AchievementsMenu` is declared globally, if that is what you are asking

Comment: Well you need to edit your post with more code. I created the same amount of code you pasted, and there are no issues. You have some other underlying issue.

Comment: @SunnyPatel Sorry about that, but I edited. Let me know if you need more code or any confusion persists. For the sake of space, effort and time I didn't include the entire class constructor because I didn't think I needed to, so sorry about that. I'll check back in a couple hours.

Comment: Review your code carefully. I just extracted your full obfuscated function declaration, and still no issues. Normally syntax errors in a function would cause your function to not be defined, and so causing the issue. But it's not happening for me.

Comment: @SunnyPatel Alright, thanks a ton for the help anyways

Comment: Here's what I extracted and put together: https://repl.it/repls/StunningComplexVariables